# Physics engine that can handle multiple attractors?

Tags: physics, algorithm, physics-engine

I'm putting together a game that will be played mostly with three dimensional gravity.

By that I mean multiple planets/stars/moons behaving realistically, and path plotting and path prediction in the gravity field.

I have looked at a variety of physics engines, such as [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/), [tokamak](http://www.tokamakphysics.com/) or [Newton](http://newtondynamics.com/forum/newton.php), but none of them seem to be suitable, as I'd essentially have to re-write the gravity engine in their framework.

**Do you know of a physics engine that is capable of dealing with multiple bodies all attracted to one another?**

I don't need scenegraph management, or rendering, just core physics. (collision detection would be a bonus, as would rigid body dynamics).

---

My background is in physics, so I would be able to write an engine that uses Verlet integration or RK4 (or even Euler integration, if I had to) but I'd much rather adapt an off the shelf solution.

**[edit]:** There are some great [resources](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/math/multistep.html) for [physics](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/) simulation of [n-body problems](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/physics/) online, and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182609/what-are-some-algorithms-that-will-allow-me-to-simulate-planetary-physics/9735124#9735124)

Comment: Can't you simply use Bullet and opt out of its standard gravity force somehow? (e.g. avoid calling applyGravity, call setGravity with a zero vector, use BT_DISABLE_WORLD_GRAVITY...)

Just because your desired effect happens to be a form of gravity doesn't mean you need to be able to achieve it through the "gravity" APIs of the underlying physics engine.

Comment: You could use some sort of inverse springs

Comment: @RoyT. A spring per se has a force proportional to d whereas gravity is d^(-2) (not even d^(-1)). You can get *orbits* from both, but with very different characteristics. If you just mean “use a distance-based constraint provided by the engine”, then yes — if it has an inverse-square one.

Comment: @KevinReid you're probably right, but I'm not sure I get your explanation. Do you mean spring forces are linear dependent on distance and gravity is inverse-square dependent?

Comment: @RoyT. Yes, exactly. Springs have a particular behavior, and there isn't any straightforward sort of "inverse" that makes them match gravity.

Comment: @Neverender That was my first though too, but applying gravity as per-step forces doesn't get you path prediction. ([Osmos](http://www.hemispheregames.com/osmos/) comes to mind as a game that has path prediction with attractors; perhaps something has been said publicly about its physics engine?)

Comment: Osmos is a great little game. the best I could find was [this](http://www.indiegamepod.com/?p=1177) interview

Comment: @KevinReid: you mention inverse square constraints provided by Bullet. I couldn't find them in the API or by searching the forums, would you have a pointer to the docs?

Comment: @brice I said “if it has” — I wouldn't expect to find one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you are going to be able to use a conventional timeslice physics engine because of the [three body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) is not going to allow for stable orbits.

You might be able to yank the physics engine out of Stellarium or some other astronomy package.

However, I think the best course of action is to simply bake in your planet's paths and pull them out of a table. Unless your player can actually affect the trajectory of planets by his actions there is no point doing a full simulation.

Comment: Actually, w.r.t the N-body problem, you _can_ get stable orbits. It depends on your method of integration. I've managed stable orbits with both verlet and RK4.

Comment: It's a fair suggestion to pre compute the paths, but I'd like to dynamically generate the systems on the fly, and also, the planets are not really what I'm worried about. I actually want the **ships** to be affected by gravity, and since these will be under player control, can't pre compute the paths.

Comment: The way to get stable orbits, for the record, is to make symmetrical systems. Also, the timescales for instability are much longer than the length of an average game would be. (unstable over 100s to 1000s of planetary orbits, while the game would not last longer than 4/5)

Comment: For examples of stable orbits, have a look at [this](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/physics/binary.html) (uses Verlet)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any platform limitation? Because [PhysX](http://developer.nvidia.com/physx), from nVidia, has [exactly what you are looking for, and more](http://developer.nvidia.com/physx-features-2x#forcefield).

Comment: Cheers @YuriAlbuquerque that's quite an interesting lead. I'm planning to do the physics server-side and the rendering client--side, so I'll have to check whether it's suitable, but that sounds good.